# Cholesky decomposition generating NaNs in Java

Tags: java, linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

I'm not sure whether this is a maths.se or a SO question, but I'm going with SO as I think it's related to my Java.

I'm following a text book on Gaussian Processes ([R&W](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml)) and implementing some examples in Java. One common step for several examples is to generate a Cholesky decomposition of a covariance matrix. In my attempt I can get successful results for matrices up to a limited size (33x33). However, for anything larger a NaN appears in the diagonal (at 32,32) and so all subsequent values in the matrix are likewise NaNs.

The code is shown below, and the source of the NaN is indicated in the `cholesky` method. Essentially the covariance element `a[32][32]` is 1.0, but the value of `sum` is a little over this (1.0000001423291431), so the square root is imaginary. So my questions are:

1. Is this an expected result from linear algebra, or, e.g., an
   artefact of my implementation?
2. How is this problem best avoided in practice?

Note that I'm not looking for recommendations of libraries to use. This is simply for my own understanding.

Apologies for the length, but I've tried to provide a complete MWE:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CholeskyTest {

    @Test
    public void testCovCholesky() {
        final int n = 34; // Test passes for n<34
        final double[] xData = getSpread(-5, 5, n);
        double[][] cov = covarianceSE(xData);
        double[][] lower = cholesky(cov);
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
                assertFalse("NaN at " + i + "," + j, Double.isNaN(lower[i][j]));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generate n evenly space values from min to max inclusive
     */
    private static double[] getSpread(final double min, final double max, final int n) {
        final double[] values = new double[n];
        final double delta = (max - min)/(n - 1);
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            values[i] = min + i*delta;
        }
        return values;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the covariance matrix for the given observations using
     * the squared exponential (SE) covariance function.
     */
    private static double[][] covarianceSE (double[] v) {
        final int m = v.length;
        double[][] k = new double[m][];
        for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
            double vi = v[i];
            double row[] = new double[m];
            for(int j=0; j<m; ++j) {
                double dist = vi - v[j];
                row[j] = Math.exp(-0.5*dist*dist);
            }
            k[i] = row;
        }
        return k;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate lower triangular matrix L such that LL^T = A
     * Using Cholesky decomposition from
     * https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Java
     */
    private static double[][] cholesky(double[][] a) {
        final int m = a.length;
        double[][] l = new double[m][m];
        for(int i = 0; i< m;i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < (i+1); k++){
                double sum = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
                    sum += l[i][j] * l[k][j];
                }
                l[i][k] = (i == k) ? Math.sqrt(a[i][i] - sum) : // Source of NaN at 32,32
                    (1.0 / l[k][k] * (a[i][k] - sum));
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I think I've found an answer to my own question, from the same textbook I was following. From [R&W](http://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters) p.201:

> In practice it may be necessary to add a small multiple of the
>   identity matrix $\epsilon I$ to the covariance matrix for numerical
>   reasons. This is because the eigenvalues of the matrix K can decay
>   very rapidly [...] and without this stabilization the Cholesky
>   decomposition fails. The effect on the generated samples is to add
>   additional independent noise of variance $epsilon$.

So the following change seems to be sufficient:

```
private static double[][] cholesky(double[][] a) {
    final int m = a.length;
    double epsilon = 0.000001; // Small extra noise value
    double[][] l = new double[m][m];
    for(int i = 0; i< m;i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < (i+1); k++){
            double sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
                sum += l[i][j] * l[k][j];
            }
            l[i][k] = (i == k) ? Math.sqrt(a[i][i]+epsilon - sum) : // Add noise to diagonal values
                (1.0 / l[k][k] * (a[i][k] - sum));
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: That is probably a better solution than my brief investigation into using `BigDecimal` to solve this.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Ah yes, that was my original thought (to use greater precision floats). Great minds think alike ;-)

Comment: Or is it “fools seldom differ”?  :-p

Comment: @AJNeufeld The latter ;-P But serioulsly: Whenever precision problems cause the recommendation to use `BigDecimal`, I shudder a bit. Imagine how the code above would look like with `BigDecimal`. (Apart from that, they basically cause the problem to be shifted to using the right rounding modes, scales etc - that's not trivial either)

Comment: Yes, quite ugly.  Notice, I only said brief investigation— never recommended it.  The lack of a `BigDecimal.sqrt` was only part of it.  Java’s lack of both `long double` and operator overloading makes math heavy programming difficult, sadly.  There is Scala, however... :-)

Comment: Hi , I think the book refers to adding a random (probably normal) noise of small variance to the diagonal elements, instead of a constant. I guess adding constant noise might not have desired effect. Thanks for the reference and code :)

Answer (score 0):

I just finished writing my own version of a Cholesky Decomposition routine in C++ and JavaScript. Instead of computing L, it computes U, but I would be curious to test it with the matrix that causes the NaN error. Would you be able to post the matrix here, or contact me (info in Profile.)

Comment: The code's all there in the test: the matrix values are generated woth `covarianceSE(getSpread(-5, 5, 34));`. The matrix is symmetric so I'd be surprised if calculating U is any different to L.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, and likely deleted soon.

Comment: @Marco13: Maybe so. But I had no other way to interact with the OP. I tried to comment on his original post, and an error message popped up, "You must have 50 reputation to comment." And he has no contact info in his Profile. So I replied the only way I could.

Comment: @beldaz Yes, the results should be the transpose of each other. However, I have made several tweaks to the naive algorithm described in textbooks, and am curious to know how it might handle potentially difficult problems.